# Bug in "Century from Year"

Tags: javascript

Goal is to return the century for a given year.

I'm aware that there's a couple solutions posted but I'm having a tough time seeing where my code fails.

What year does this code get the century wrong for?

Inputs are 1 `<= x <= 2005`.

```
function centuryFromYear(year) {

    if (year % 100 > 0){
        if (year % 100 > 50) {
            return Math.round(year / 100);
        } else {
            return (Math.round((year / 100)) +1);
        }
    } else {
        return Math.round((year / 100)); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Side note: both else could be removed here.

Comment: Does not seem to be wrong for 1 to 2005. You can verify by logging the outputs. Any other info?

Comment: Create a simple loop to output the year and the function's results. Quick example, year 150 has a problem. Why? the way JS implements `round`. "If the fractional portion of the argument is greater than 0.5, the argument is rounded to the integer with the next higher absolute value. If it is less than 0.5, the argument is rounded to the integer with the lower absolute value.  If the fractional portion is exactly 0.5, the argument is rounded to the next integer in the direction of +∞.  ...

Comment: @j08691 indeed, as for any year ending with 50. `Math.round(1.5)` returns 2 and not 1, which will cause a bug.

Comment: "...Note that this differs from many languages' round() functions, which often round this case to the next integer away from zero, instead giving a different result in the case of negative numbers with a fractional part of exactly 0.5.""

Comment: thanks, `if (year % 100 > 50)` should be `if (year % 100 >= 50)`

Comment: how about `century = Math.ceil(year / 100)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noted in my comments above, the issue arises from the way [JavaScript rounds numbers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round).

> If the fractional portion of the argument is greater than 0.5, the
>   argument is rounded to the integer with the next higher absolute
>   value. If it is less than 0.5, the argument is rounded to the integer
>   with the lower absolute value.  If the fractional portion is exactly
>   0.5, the argument is rounded to the next integer in the direction of +∞.  **Note that this differs from many languages' round() functions, which often round this case to the next integer away from zero**,
>   instead giving a different result in the case of negative numbers with
>   a fractional part of exactly 0.5.

You can see the issue here:

```js
function centuryFromYear(year) {
  if (year % 100 > 0) {
    if (year % 100 > 50) {
      return Math.round(year / 100);
    } else {
      return (Math.round((year / 100)) + 1);
    }
  } else {
    return Math.round((year / 100));
  }
}

for (let i = 1; i <= 2005; i++) {
  console.log(i, centuryFromYear(i))
}
```

Every time you hit a year ending in exactly `50` the rounding issue comes into play and rounds up with `Math.round((year / 100)) + 1` when it should be hitting `Math.round(year / 100)`. A simple solution is to change `if (year % 100 > 50)` to `if (year % 100 >= 50)`

```js
function centuryFromYear(year) {
  if (year % 100 > 0) {
    if (year % 100 >= 50) {
      return Math.round(year / 100);
    } else {
      return (Math.round((year / 100)) + 1);
    }
  } else {
    return Math.round((year / 100));
  }
}

for (let i = 1; i <= 2005; i++) {
  console.log(i, centuryFromYear(i))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is correct code:

```
if (year % 100 > 0){
    if (year % 100 >= 50) {
        return Math.round(year / 100);
    } else {
        return (Math.round((year / 100)) +1);
    }
} else {
    return Math.round((year / 100)+1); 
}
```

You forgot to add (year / 100)+1 in the else of your first if loop, which is why if fails for cases like 2000, 1900, 1800 etc.

Comment: 1950 still results in 21 instead of 20th century.

Comment: no, sorry. That incorrectly returns 18 for `year = 1700` for example. Answer in the comments above, was forgetting an `=` to catch cases where `year % 100 = 50`